# How to redirect traffic coming from exterior to a proxy chains of 2 proxy?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, iptables

I'm using redsocks to redirect the incoming non-local traffic to forward it to a socks5 proxy. Unfortunately,redsocks does not support proxy chaining, So I tried to do a turn around by running 2 redsocks instance. I tried to do with iptables to redirect the external packet to the first redsocks instance by doing:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS
```

and to resend the the new packet to the second proxy, I run:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS1
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS1 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12346
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS1
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS1
```

The problem is I that the TCP connection is directly made with the final destination and not with the second proxy then the final destination. I also use microsocks to run proxy servers. Can u help me to try to fix that ? Thank u and have a nice day. :D
The first redsocks configuration :

```
base {
//omitted
 redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
    local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
    local_port = 12345;

    ip = 127.0.0.1;
    port = 1080;
    type = socks5;
        }
```

The second redsocks configuration:

```
base {
//omited
 redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    local_port = 12346;

    ip = 34.77.235.223; //fictive IP
    port = 1080;
    type = socks5;
     }
```

Also